# using regular expressions to highlight links in a text

Tags: javascript

hi i am trying to highlight links in a text using RegEx ,For this I tried with match() method and replace() method,
  but i didn't get it.plz any one can help me.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
               <script type="text/javascript" >

        function findReplace() {
            var srcString = document.getElementById('new').innerHTML;
            var pattern = new RegExp("<[^<]+</a>", 'ig');
            var newString = srcString.match(pattern);
            for (var i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
              var replaced = srcString.replace(pattern, '<div style="background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;"> ' + newString[i] + ' </div>')

            document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = replaced

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='button'  id='btn'value='Match' onclick="findReplace()"  />
    <div id='new'>
    Finally we  have succeeded! <a href='#'>Remember</a> that if you just want to replace one word,
     you should use a string or normal regular expression as your searchFor parameter. However, 
     if you want to replace <a href='#'>google</a> be sure to write a <a href='#'>regularexpression</a> and append a little g at the end!
     </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Why use a din and set display to inline? Why not use span instead?

Comment: Whoops - I overlooked your question a bit... You actually wanted to change a-elements to div-elements? How about just returning false for the link, ie. prevent it from working (then my previous answer would still be valid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your work, here is a solution :

```
function findReplace() {

     var pattern = new RegExp("(<a[^<]+</a>)", 'ig');
     document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = document.getElementById('new').innerHTML.replace(pattern, '<div style="background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;">$1</div>');
 }
```

If I were you, I would use the DOM with document.getElementsByTagName('a') instead of Regex + innerHTML property and your regex won't match :

```
<a href="efefe.html"><strong>okokok</strong></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here would be a different kind of solution that would get rid of the regexp...

```
function highlightLinks () {
  //Get div id
  divElement = document.getElementById('new');

  //Get links in div
  var links = divElement.getElementsByTagName('a');

  //Change link styles
  for (var i=0, end=links.length; i<end; i++) {
    links[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    links[i].style.display= 'inline';
    links[i].style.fontWeight= 'bold';
  }
}
```

Or a jQuery equivalent...

```
$("#div > a").css({'background-color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold', 'display':'inline'});
```

Sorry, I couldn't test either of these, but bot should work. Correct me if I'm incorrect... ;)

Comment: I also recommend using getElementByTagName and changing style or adding a class (easy with jQuery) instead of regex, it much easier and less likely to break on bad code.